# variable inside a jquery .on

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey just wanted to ask if there's anyway you can put a variable inside a jquery function like on a onlick

```
onclick="function(variable)"
```

This is my button which when click should send a ID

`echo "<button id='upvote'><img style='height: 100%; width: 100%;   object-fit: contain;' src='..\images\caret-arrow-up_318-42194.jpg'></button><br>";`

And go into this jquery .on

```
$(".Reviews").on("click", "#upvote", function(){
         });
```

Comment: you can use HTML-5 data-* attributes, https://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5

Comment: if you just need to send a string then just put it in a data attribute and get it inside of the handler. `<button data-id="xxx" ... >` then inside of your click handler you can grab that with `$(this).data('id')` If you just need the ID from the actual button then you can just grab that with `this.id`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use the data- attribute to pass values with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18167550/how-do-i-use-the-data-attribute-to-pass-values-with-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do this but one way (and probably the best way IMO) is to use `data-` attributes:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".Reviews").on("click", "#upvote", function(){
   var myData = $(this).data('mydata');
   console.log(myData);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="Reviews">
<a href="#" data-mydata="mydata" id="upvote">Test me</a>
</div>
```

Note the attribute `data-mydata` is read using the syntax `.data('mydata');`

Answer (score -1):

If I understood you right, you can give the buttons a `name` and use it as following:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".Reviews").click(function() {
    $name = $(this).attr("name");
    if ($name == 'upvote') {
      alert('upvoted');
    } else if ($name == 'downvote') {
      alert('downvoted');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='button' class='Reviews' name='upvote' value='upvote' />
<input type='button' class='Reviews' name='downvote' value='downvote' />
```

I hope this is what you meant, if not, leave a comment and I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks alot i used data- insted but tried yours to and it worked